# Django defining custom routing rules

Tags: python, django

I come from a TypeScript/Express.js background when it comes to developing APIs, and normally we have a custom `AuthRouter` that we structure similar to below (implementation scrubbed for client security).  We do our auth by taking a Bearer token and sending it to an external API for validation:

```js
// app.ts
/* Express app setup */

app.use(AuthRouter);

/* Other modules that define our other app routes/services */

// AuthRouter.ts

router = express.Router()

router.all(config.API_BASE + '*', async (req, res, next) => {
    validate(req.headers.authorization)
    next();
});
```

Is there a similar way to achieve the same routing flow in Django?  I've already looked into defining a custom Authentication Backend, but I'm afraid it won't play nice since it appears to be coupled to a "User" which isn't the goal, so i can't satisfy the minimum requirements.  Is leaving the `get_user` function empty a valid approach?

Ideally, I'm looking for whatever can simulate that `next()` callback that Express provides.  If I have to setup the callback functionality myself, I will, although I think that could get pretty hairy.

Any tips would be appreicated!!

Comment: Check out django rest framework, I think it will provide everything necessary with routing and auth. It is the most supported django app and is essentially a core part of django.

Comment: I don't understand "it appears to be couple to a 'User' which isn't the goal". How can you authenticate without a user? And I mean this in the broadest sense (user doesn't necessarily need to be a human, it can be another server)? What are you authenticating against? In Django every request always has a user object.

Comment: DRF suggested by @SamCreamer is good, provides Token Authentication out of the box, but you're talking about 3rd party API for authentication, so maybe you'll need one of the other auth backend mentioned [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages)